# Draftjs how to save input data to LocalStorage without overwriting the previous data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state, draftjs

I am using a draftjs rich text editor to save my text input to local storage. Right now, my program is able to take text input and when I click save, it saves the text input to my local storage. Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";

class SaveData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  getContentAsRawJson() {
    const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const raw = convertToRaw(contentState);
    return JSON.stringify(raw, null, 2);
  }
  saveContent() {
    const json = this.getContentAsRawJson();
    localStorage.setItem("savedContent", json);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button onClick={this.saveContent.bind(this)}>Save Content</button>
        <pre>{this.getContentAsRawJson}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SaveData;
```

[The input from the text editor saved in local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJBFt.png)

However, I need the saveContent() function to not overwrite the existing content that is already saved in my local storage.
An example of what I want to achieve would look like:

- I put in some text in the text editor, click save,  the text is saved
  in my local storage.
- Then I add some new text in the text editor,    click save, the text
  is saved alongside my previous input without    overwriting it.
- Load both text inputs into the text editor.

I believe I need to save the states to an array in the local storage, and whenever I press save, it would append the new data at the end of the array. But I'm lost as to how to achieve this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When the component mounts or updates fetch the `text` from `localStorage` if it exists and set it inside state. Then update the state on text change and on save set the `localStorage` text from state `text`.